# Diffing a new file in CVS

Tags: cvs

I'm trying to generate a diff between a few of my files, one of them is a newly added file in CVS (I did a cvs add myfile.py).

When I try to generate the diff, cvs diff -u (all my files) it complains saying cvs diff: myfile.py is a new entry, no comparison available.

How do I get it to generate the diff file with my new file in it too? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cvs diff -Nu
```

Use the `-N` flag. From `cvs diff --help`:

> -N  --new-file  Treat absent files as empty.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I get -- Cannot use reserved filename 'nul' on NT based machines.